# CSS: Fixed Position of Inner Divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to import user's facebook friends in a div. `Friend Divs` are not positioned properly. They are jumbling around based on length of the name.

```
Note:I was not able to show full name of friends because it was hard to fit in a small Friend Div.
```

**CSS**

```
#jfmfs-friend-container {
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-x: hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:7.6em;  
    color: #333;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.jfmfs-friend {                
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    height:3em;
    width:12em;
    font-size:11px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0.40em;
}
.friend-name  {
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.friend-checkbox {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px;
}

.friend-img {
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="jfmfs-friend-container">
<div class="jfmfs-friend  " id="00000000000"><input class="friend-checkbox" type="checkbox"><img src="//graph.facebook.com/000000000/picture" class="friend-img"><span class="friend-name">hhhhhHy uuuu</span></div>
<div class="jfmfs-friend  " id="00000000012"><input class="friend-checkbox" type="checkbox"><img src="//graph.facebook.com/00000000012/picture" class="friend-img"><span class="friend-name">hhhhhHy uuuu</span></div>
<div class="jfmfs-friend  " id="00000000330"><input class="friend-checkbox" type="checkbox"><img src="//graph.facebook.com/00000000330/picture" class="friend-img"><span class="friend-name">hhhhhHy uuuu</span></div>
<div class="jfmfs-friend  " id="00000000044"><input class="friend-checkbox" type="checkbox"><img src="//graph.facebook.com/00000000044/picture" class="friend-img"><span class="friend-name">hhhhhHy uuuu</span></div>
<div class="jfmfs-friend  " id="00000000880"><input class="friend-checkbox" type="checkbox"><img src="//graph.facebook.com/00000000880/picture" class="friend-img"><span class="friend-name">hhhhhHy uuuu</span></div>
<div class="jfmfs-friend  " id="00000000770"><input class="friend-checkbox" type="checkbox"><img src="//graph.facebook.com/00000000770/picture" class="friend-img"><span class="friend-name">hhhhhHy uuuu</span></div>
</div>
```

**Actual Result:**
[image]

Comment: Your html is not valid. An id attribute cannot contain a # and should not start with a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `display:inline-block;` to `.friend-name`

like this- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Yyjxe/)

```
.friend-name  {
    display:inline-block; 
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 70px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: It does the trick but now full names are appearing and are not fitting into the div height. Friend Names are a problem here, they can be very long, so just want to First Name if they don't fit into the div.

Comment: In your fiddle too, name's height is more than image height.